# After separation, my husband tried to rape our daughter; can I get a divorce?

Tags: talaq

I have been married for 15 years we have 3 children, the 1st child is now 14 and she is a girl and my husband tried to rape her due to that we have not been living together past six months and I (the wife) now want a divorce and to get married again.

What should I do?  Please give me the right path as one wrong information could lead to sins of a lifetime.

Comment: So far i can only tell you my opinion: First it's only the man who can give divorce, but you can ask for it on a court because of the rape issue.

Comment: First of all, you need to clarify one part: "Me and the wife now want to..." Who is the wife in this? Please edit your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: She meant herself. She meant 'Me the wife' as corrected by Medi.